# pyscripter is not loading with python installed

Tags: python, ide

I recently installed `python-3.6.3-amd64.exe` and `PyScripter-v3.0.2-Setup.exe`
However `PyScripter` fails to load with message

> Phyton could not be initialized.

I need an python IDE. Actually I do not care so much which to use as long as they work and start without trouble. How can I fix this problem?